# difference between artificial neural network and Bayesian network

Tags: neural-network, bayesian-networks

I am a student working on an internship project where in we are using Bayesian networks to predict a possible outcome from a given set of discrete parent variables.We now intend to use artificial neural network to do the task.So could any one please help me out with the similarities and differences between Bayesian networks and artificial neural network?Any suggestions as how to proceed with migration would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Similarity**

- Both use directed graphs.

**Difference**

- In Bayesian networks the vertices and edges have meaning- The network structure itself gives you valuable information about conditional dependence between the variables. With Neural Networks the network structure does not tell you anything.

Comment: That's a great answer. So to help my understanding, would it be fair to say that they can both act as decision making agents, but where a Bayesian network is hardwired, a neural network is programmable, and as a result, a neural network can be made to function as a Bayesian network?

Comment: @Charlie A Bayesian network encodes a probability distribution. A neural network (effectively) encodes a mapping between a set of input values and a set of output values. So they are fundamentally different. Sure you could use either to help make decisions. I disagree with a Bayesian network being "hardwired", a given network is "hardwired" in the same sense that a trained Neural network is "hardwired". Either tool can be used to fit data.